# Facing an error in android studio, it says cannot resolve symbol 'JitsiMeetConferenceOptions'

Tags: java, android, jitsi

So basically i need help in understanding how to use jitsi android sdk in android studio because when i try to integrate it using the steps given in its documentation, it throws an error.
I have added this dependency in build.gradle(module)

```
implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:+') { transitive = true }
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiFZW.png)
[dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXTUC.png)

Comment: you'll need to show your actual code. It might be the scope. I'm not familiar with this library, but you may have a missing dependency. There are quite a few options

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Should add proper version of the implementation

> implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:5.1.0') { transitive
> = true }

Comment: Tried this but didn't worked